# Parse WSDL file using Apex code

Tags: apex, wsdl, parser

I want to parse WSDL file in apex manually. Is there any API or can anyone please share code snippet for parsing WSDL in apex class.

Comment: Do you u want to parse XML?  or you want parse WSDL and generate APEX class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a current implementation to handle this. However, the basic parts are available for parsing XML documents using Dom.Document and Dom.XMLNode or XmlStreamReader.

See:

- [Reading and Writing XML Using the DOM](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_xml_dom.htm)
- [Reading XML Using Streams](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_xml_streaming_reading.htm)

What is your intention after your have consumed the WSDL? To dynamically make callouts and process the responses?

I don't know more than the Dreamforce 14 description, but the following session may be of interest:

> ## Building Callouts Without WSDL2Apex and Apex Parsers
>
> On the Force.com platform, there are two ways of building Apex callout modules to invoke external web services and to retrieve data out of the responses. However, each approach has pitfalls that can slow down the whole development process. Join us to learn a different approach when developing callout code. The core part in this approach is a strategy design pattern consisting of one generic XML parser and one JSON parser. Based on the content-type HTTP header at run time, one of them will be utilized to parse any SOAP, XML or JSON stream returned from service endpoint. The parser also stores data values in a map structure. Developers can then use a set of simple API methods and XPath strings to retrieve any values out of the map directly.

Comment: I want to develop tool like SoapUI. For that purpose, first I am trying to parse WSDL file in Apex class manually and find list of methods present in that class.